# Using HikariCP as connection pool with GemfireXD in a Spring boot application throws ClassCastException

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp, gemfire

I am trying to use **HikariCP** with **Gemfire XD** in a **Spring boot application**.I am getting below ClassCastException:`

```
10:29:04.757 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Started.
10:29:04.791 [main] WARN  c.z.hikari.util.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.ClientConnectionPoolDataSource was not found, trying direct instantiation.
10:29:04.794 [main] WARN  c.z.hikari.util.DriverDataSource - Failed to create instance of driver class com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.ClientConnectionPoolDataSource, trying jdbcUrl resolution
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.ClientConnectionPoolDataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:71)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:298)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:91)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:101)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:94)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:615)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658)
```

I have specified below configurations in application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:gemfirexd://192.168.162.141:1527/
spring.datasource.username=APP
spring.datasource.password=APP
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.ClientConnectionPoolDataSource
spring.datasource.schema=APP
spring.datasource.transaction-isolation=0
spring.datasource.auto-commit=true`**
```

And as per the [BlogPost](http://theblasfrompas.blogspot.in/2013/12/hikaricp-connection-pool-with-pivotal.html) I have tried changing to
**spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.ClientDataSource**

But still it does not work and throws same exception.

Gemfire XD Version:1.4.1
HikariCP Version:2.4.6
Spring boot Version:1.3.5
Spring JDBC version:4.2.6
Java Version :1.7

Comment: a `javax.sql.Driver` is not a `javax.sql.DataSource`. So yes you will get a class cast exception if you try to assign a datasource to a driver property.